# Trigger.IO: Including an mp3 file

Tags: trigger.io

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour when including an mp3 in the src (or any other sub folder) of a very simple trigger.io project.

The first build works fine. On the second build I recieve the following error: 
(I've added translations for the german stuff)

```
2012-07-13 12:51:38,017 [  DEBUG] Checking API response for success or error
2012-07-13 12:51:38,131 [  DEBUG] configuration is identical to last run
2012-07-13 12:51:38,131 [  DEBUG] already authenticated - continuing
2012-07-13 12:51:38,131 [  DEBUG] GET https://trigger.io/api/app/69c8695eccc911e1a8c212313d1adcbe/should_rebuild
2012-07-13 12:51:38,394 [  DEBUG] Checking API response for success or error
2012-07-13 12:51:38,394 [   INFO] Configuration is unchanged: using existing templates
2012-07-13 12:51:48,394 [  ERROR] Something went wrong that we didn't expect:
2012-07-13 12:51:48,394 [  ERROR] [Error 183] Eine Datei kann nicht erstellt werden, wenn sie bereits vorhanden ist: 'development'
Translation: A file cannot be created if it exists allready: 'development'
2012-07-13 12:51:48,394 [  DEBUG] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asic\forge-tools-3.3.2\forge-tools\forge\async.py", line 96, in run
    result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\asic\forge-tools-3.3.2\forge-tools\forge\main.py", line 369, in development_build
    try_a_few_times(move_files_across)
  File "C:\Users\asic\forge-tools-3.3.2\forge-tools\forge\lib.py", line 25, in try_a_few_times
    f()
  File "C:\Users\asic\forge-tools-3.3.2\forge-tools\forge\main.py", line 365, in move_files_across
    shutil.copytree(defaults.TEMPLATE_DIR, 'development')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 174, in copytree
    os.makedirs(dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 183] Eine Datei kann nicht erstellt werden, wenn sie bereits vorhanden ist: 'development'
Translation: A file cannot be created if it exists allready: 'development'
```

The only way to fix it, is to delete the development folder and build from scratch..

Comment: Maybe something has a file lock on the Mp3?

Comment: Can (or did) you include the --verbose parameter? forge build --verbose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we do a 'forge build' the existing 'development' directory is deleted and recreated. So if you have the .mp3 open within another app on Windows that may prevent the file being deleted, hence seeing this problem on the second 'forge build'.

Comment: thanks! the mp3 actually had the readonly attribute set. That kept the build process from properly deleting the folder.